# Capturing UIImageview to image in Objective C who contain an UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a UIimageview that i have a transparent rect that i can resize by drag the problem is i couldn't save the image (with the recant above)

i tried

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithViewOld:(UIView *)view
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```

but it only show my UIImageview without my custom UIview

i even tried adding

```
     [view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
     [self.myRect.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
```

but in the generated image i can see the rect but above my image not inside

Comment: can you please clarify? why are you using the second transparent view?

Comment: myRect is a transparent view that the user can drag inside the image but wasn't captured with the image

Comment: Try drawViewHierarchyInRect

Comment: if anyway interested, i added my uiview as subview of my uiimageview and now i get the image containing mu custom view

Comment: @SocoM you have to put [self.view bringSubviewToFront:desiredView]in view did load

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have an image view and you want to drag the transparent view over the image view and saved a cropped version of the image view. The issue with how it sounds like your code is set up, is that both of these views are siblings. The easiest solution you can do is add the transparent view as a subview to the image view and then use `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`.

```
-(UIImage *)imageWithViewOld:(UIView *)view croppedTo:(CGRect)rect
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
    [view drawViewHierarchyInRect:rect afterScreenUpdates:NO];

    UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return img;
}
```